# Import module error from channel conda-forge

Tags: python, conda, conda-forge

I fail at importing a certain module that has been installed on conda-forge channel. As you can see, the module is present if I run

> conda list

Under the correct environment. However, if I run a .py script in the very same conda environment, the module is not found. In particular, I cannot import module "betfairlightweight".

[image]

Is it because it is not in the default conda channel? If so, how can I import modules from both the default channel and the conda-forge one?

**The script is called simply as**

> (scraper) C:\Users\frasl\betting\betting\spiders\bet python files> API_2.py

where (scraper) is the conda environment where the packages are installed.

**The part of the script failing is the import, so:**

> import betfairlightweight
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'betfairlightweight'

All the modules installed only on the conda-forge channel fail at import, while all the other modules, such as pandas, numpy, json are working properly.

I am using the **Anaconda Prompt**.

EDIT:

**If I run:**

> (scraper) C:\Users\frasl\betting\betting\spiders\bet python files>python API_2.py

Then module "betfairlightweight" **does not** give import error, however, pandas does:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "API_2.py", line 2, in
>
> import pandas as pd
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you could include the exact command you used to run the script and the part of the script that imports the library :-)

Comment: Could you please include the command you used to run the script?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: You need to recreate your env. See the mixture of Conda and Pip packages of the same names? That indicates the env is in an unstable state and there's really no reliable way to predict how it's going to behave. Try making a YAML: `conda env export -n scraper > scraper.yaml`. Go through and delete whatever is in the `pip` section that is already in the regular dependencies section. Then recreate the env using this reduced YAML. Please read "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)" for tips on avoiding such states in the future.

Comment: Thank you, @merv. I kinda solved it for now by using the "python" command before the name of the script and by installing through conda pandas and all the other packages that were previously installed through pip. But I will definetely do as you suggested as soon as any issue like that rises again. I guess that one should always use **either** the conda (or conda-forge) installer **or** the pip installer in a single environment?

Comment: @FS93 yes, basically once `pip` is used, `conda` doesn't "know" about the true state of the env. The best practice is to stick to `conda` and if you do have to use `pip` only do it at the end. The ideal workflow is to always use an `env.yaml` file to create an env, and when you need to add something, edit that file, then create a new version of the env with `conda env create -f env.yaml`.